# Trying to inline images with caption in horizontal not vertical

Tags: html, css

```css
.col-xs-4{
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 2em;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3{
    color: #09423f;
}


p{
    color: black;
}


#works{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>HOW IT WORKS</h1>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="img/create.svg" class="img-responsive" id="works" alt="create">
        <h3><b>CREATE YOUR IDEAS</b></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae purus nibh. Vestibulum vehicula vitae tellus non tincidunt. Aenean magna ipsum, ultricies ac ante non, maximus suscipit lectus. Donec tincidunt velit augue, in egestas est ultrices eget. Suspendisse commodo mi nulla, sed condimentum purus lobortis ut.</p>
        </div>
        
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="img/sell.svg" class="img-responsive" id="works" alt="sell">
        <h3><b>POST IT</b></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae purus nibh. Vestibulum vehicula vitae tellus non tincidunt. Aenean magna ipsum, ultricies ac ante non, maximus suscipit lectus. Donec tincidunt velit augue, in egestas est ultrices eget. Suspendisse commodo mi nulla, sed condimentum purus lobortis ut </p>
        </div>
    
    
   <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="img/earn.svg" class="img-responsive" id="works" alt="earn">
    <h3><b>EARN IT</b></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae purus nibh. Vestibulum vehicula vitae tellus non tincidunt. Aenean magna ipsum, ultricies ac ante non, maximus suscipit lectus. Donec tincidunt velit augue, in egestas est ultrices eget. Suspendisse commodo mi nulla, sed condimentum purus lobortis ut</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I want to try to align all three images with caption in one line. I try float: left but all three didn't work. I try other way too but it remains same. Please help me. You give me right answer I would click green tick.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I want 3 columns contain images along with text or caption in line like eg. thumbnail. i don't want to align in vertical-align but in horizontal.

Comment: @AlziraBarretto look at my answer, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't attached your bootsrap CDN's though you was using Bootstrap like `col-xs-4`, attach it and then you Boxes will align perfectly horizontal

Bootstrap CDN attach this at the `<head>`

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and remove following class which is unnecessary

```
.col-xs-4{
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 2em;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/graKZe

Answer (score 1):

add this

```css
.col-xs-4{
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-xs-4 img{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a bootstrap cdn in your code.

And because of the clear:both in your (.col-xs-4) inside CSS you could not align them horizontally.

plunker copy attached: [enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/CaVfVz?p=info)

```
.col-xs-4{
margin: auto;
padding-left: 2em;
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;
```

}

```
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
```